# What is the advantage of Bubblewrap VS Android native webview

Tags: android-webview, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, bubblewrap

What would be a practical advantage of using bubblewrap vs Android webview. What is the major difference between both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bubblewrap is a tool that turns your PWA into an Android app package (apk+aab) just by reading its `manifest.json`. No Android Studio, no Java/Kotlin skills are required. The resultant package is quite small, typically less than 1 MB, and depends on [Android Browser Helper](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper) which uses Trusted Web Activity (TWA) that invokes installed system browser if it supports Custom Tabs protocol, or falls back to WebView otherwise.

WebView is a browser component which is part of the Android platform and is typically used from Java/Kotlin porgrams.

For more info: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/trusted-web-activity/